# The numbers 1 to 11 are arranged in a line (uniformly at random). What is the probability that the first number and last number are both even?

Tags: probability, permutations

I came across this question when revising:

The numbers 1 to 11 are arranged in a line (uniformly at random). What is the probability that the first number and last number are both even?

***My method***

Even numbers: 2,4,6,8,10

Odd numbers: 1,3,5,7,9,11

I was thinking since the probability for the first number to be even would be $\frac{5}{11}$ and the probability for the last number to be even would be $\frac{4}{10}$(since if the first number is already taken and is even, so there are 10 numbers left and 4 of them are even)

But upon rethinking, I started to have doubts about my method as I realised that the sequence in which the number can be placed must also be taken into account.

Does anyone know how to solve this, any help is truly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Your initial logic is correct. To help you convince yourself you can note that it is clear that the probability that the first and last elements are even is equal to the probability that the first and the second elements are even - i.e. there is nothing special about the last element.

Comment: "*I realised [sic] that the sequence in which the number can be placed must also be taken into account*"  You may assume [without loss of generality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality) that the first number is placed first, and the last number is placed second.

Comment: @JMoravitz  Realise is the British spelling.

Comment: @JMoravitz, so that means my logic is correct and I could just multiply $\frac{5}{11}$ with $\frac{4}{10}$?

Comment: Yes and is the way I would have approached as well

Comment: @JMoravitz, oh okay, thank you so much for the clarification and also for the source for (without loss of generality), never knew about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $\color{magenta}{11\times10\times9\times\cdots\times1}=\color{magenta}{11!}$ ways of permuting these numbers. Out of them, the first and the last can be chosen even in $5\times4=20$ ways so that the total number of ways in which the first and the last are even is $5\times\color{magenta}{9\times8\times7\times\cdots\times1}\times4= 20\times\color{magenta}{9!}$.

Consequently, the required probability is $$\frac{20\times 9!}{11!}=\frac{2}{11}$$

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this equals the result that the OP envisioned :)

Comment: What/who is OP?

Comment: It is an abbreviation for "original poster" and in this case refers to Bryan Hii since he asked the question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: What are the empty ```\underbrace```s for? They are just confusing as if they're indicating to some non-existential text. You might have used brackets or color for that. This is MY opinion, you can keep them as you want though, just a suggestion :-)

Comment: Suggestion acknowledged.